# Предлагаю убрать метку unity3d

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Сколько сижу в ruSO, вижу какая неиспользуемая метка [unity](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity). В любом вопросе используют метку [unity3d](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d), даже если вопрос про UI и т д.

Предлагаю удалить метку [unity3d](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d), так как метка [unity](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) более общая. А если будут задавать вопросы например про UI пусть используют метки [unity](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) и `ui`.

---

П.Н.
Если что метки [unity](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) и [unity3d](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) являются синонимами, просто [unity3d](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) какая-то "бесполезная".

Answer (score 4):

> В любом вопросе используют метку [unity3d](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d), даже если вопрос про UI и т д.

А в чём проблема? 3d - это не про то, что работа с 3d, просто движок раньше назывался с этой припиской.

Удалять ничего не надо. Метки являются синонимами.

Единственное, что можно бы было предпринять - это сделать [unity](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) основной.

Comment: тогда уж лучше сделать `unity` основной

Comment: @Арман отдельным вопрос лучше. По аналогии с [вот этими](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba).

Comment: этот тогда удалить?

Comment: @Арман не надо. Другие участники тоже могут что-то предложить)