# Может метку unity сделать главной?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть множество меток связанные с [unity](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity). Предлагаю соединить метки такие как [unity](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity), [unity3d](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d), [unity3d-android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d-android), [unity3d-editor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d-editor), [unity3d-ui](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d-ui) и сделать метку [unity](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) главной. Так как люди задавая вопросы не используют вышеперечисленные метки, а например вместо [unity3d-ui](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d-ui) используют метки [unity](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity), [ui](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ui) вместе.

---

Предистория вопроса [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10299).

Answer (score 3):

[unity](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) - общая метка, показывающая, что вопрос про Юнити.

[unity-editor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity-editor), [unity-android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity-android) - это дополнительные метки, которые указывают специфику. Они вполне самостоятельные и ничего с ними делать не надо.